# Trying to iterate over a df and add a column with a value for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use two dataframes to add a new column, `num_events` to one of my dataframes.

My first attempt was to use `iteritems()`, but I am getting the error: `KeyError: 'min_lat'`

Basic code:

```
for index, row in v_roads.iteritems():
  min_lat = row['min_lat']
  min_lon = row['min_lon']
  max_lat = row['max_lat']
  max_lon = row['max_lon']
  total_events = 0
  for i, r in accidents.iteritems():
        e_lat = r['latitude']
        e_lon = r['longitude']
        if e_lat >= min_lat and e_lat <= max_lat and e_lon >= min_lon and e_lon <= max_lon:
           total_events += 1
 row['num_events'] = total_events
```

I understand that `iteritems()` lazily iterates over (index, value) tuples, but I am unsure of another way to do what I want, which is for each row, get the data at the row's columns, `min_lat`, `min_lon`, etc. and store that data in variables.

Could someone please point me in the right direction towards a correct approach?

*EDIT*: To clear this up for some, yes I do want to add a new column, but I am stuck at reading data from specific row's columns.

**Data example**

v_roads 
[image]

accidents

[image]

Comment: Please provide a small data sample.

Comment: @BrenBarn sure thing, adding now

Comment: That sample is too small since it appears to be only one row.  Also it's not in a format that can be easily copy-pasted (or read, since it's all out of alignment).  The best thing to do is make a small data frame, post it, and also show a self-contained code snippet with output as run on that same sample data.

Comment: It's both :) But I broke it down into a simpler problem first. Look at the new data @BrenBarn

Comment: It sounds like all you want to do is either add cols from another df or just extract 4 columns, can you explain what you're trying to do as what you're doing defeats the purpose of using dfs

Comment: @EdChum So I'm new to pandas. What I want to do is store the min_lat, max_lat, etc. variable for each row in roads, and for that road, go through *every* row in events and see if the event's latitude and longitude fit inside that bounding box. If so, I will increment the number of events associated with a road and append it to a new column "num_events" for the roads dataframe.

Comment: @BrenBarn just solved this very easily :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve this this is what I did:

```
    for row in v_roads.itertuples():
       # Where 11 is the index of the min_lat col...
       min_lat = row[11]
       min_lon = row[12]
       ...
```

It's not that hard, so hopefully this helps anybody else with a similar issue.

Note that tuples are immutable, so if you wanted to make changes you would need to do something like:

```
    for i, row in v_roads.head(1000).iterrows():
       v_roads.set_value(i, 'colNameHere', variableToPlace)
```